# Making filter using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to make `filter` using `foldr`. I have a solution, but don't know why my version does not work.

`foldr` works like this:

```
>>>foldr op z (xs:x)
x op z
```

then repeats, correct? When x is the last element in the list.

Now, I have

```
myFilter pred = foldr op z
  where
    z = []
    op x xs = if pred x then x
```

this does not work, gives a `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)` error.

The operation just gives `x` to `pred` and if it is `true`, returns `x`, otherwise skips it. The way `foldr` works is that it keeps looping on the `xs` list that is passed. So why do I need to do

```
 op x xs = if pred x then x : xs else xs
```

and tell it to continue with `xs` even if `foldr` already does the continuing?

Comment: take a look at the definition of foldr here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr  
you can see `op` expects two inputs, the current element and the result of processing the rest of the elements using foldr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the type of `foldr` for a list:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Now you are using it like this:

```
foldr op z
```

From the type signature of `foldr` we see that the function `op` must return something of type `b` which is the same type as `z`. Since you do `z = []`, this must be a list. So the result of `op x xs` must be a list.

Additionally, keep in mind that `if...else` in Haskell is an **expression**. This means that it must evaluate to some value no matter if the condition is true or false. In other languages, the `else` is optional because `if` is a **statement**. In Haskell, the `else` **is not optional**.

> So why do I need to do
>
> ```
> op x xs = if pred x then x : xs else xs
> ```
>
> and tell it to continue with xs even if foldr already does the continuing?

One reason is that `op` must always return a value. This value will be used by `foldr` to continue its calculation. Without it, `foldr` is unable to continue, and in fact your code won't even compile as you saw.

Answer (score 5):

`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` loops over an input list of `a`s and manipulates a `b` (representing the loop's state). `op`'s job is to take an `a` from the input list, the current state `b`, and compute a new state. `foldr` makes sure that `op` is called for every item in the list.

In the case of your `filter`, `b` happens to also be a list of `a`s. So your code is talking about two different lists of `a`s — the input list and the output list. Your `op` has to decide *should I put this `x` in the output list or not?*

To clarify, here is your code with the variables named a bit more suggestively.

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter pred = foldr addToOutputIfNecessary initialOutput
  where
    initialOutput = []
    addToOuputIfNecessary itemFromInput currentOutput =
      if pred itemFromInput
      then itemFromInput:currentOutput
      else currentOutput
```

So when we return `currentOutput` from `addToOutputIfNecessary`, it's not about telling `foldr` to continue. (`foldr` will always continue to the next input element by itself — you don't need to tell it to continue.) It's just saying that the loop's state hasn't changed this iteration; we've decided not to add an item to the output list.

Hope this helps! Let me know in the comments if there's anything you don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

`foldr` encapsulates the recursion involved in combining an element from the list with the result of folding the rest of the list. `xs` is not the tail of your input; it's the result of *folding* the tail of your input.

You can emphasize this a bit by focusing on what you want `op` to *do*, and de-emphasizing what it operates on, by refactoring

```
op x xs = if pred x then x : xs else xs
```

to

```
-- (x:) xs == x:xs
-- id xs == xs
op x xs = (if pred x then (x:) else id) xs
```

which can be eta-reduced to

```
op x = if pred x then (x:) else id
```

In other words, given the first element of the list, what will you do with it: prepend `x` it to the recursive result, or return that result as-is?